# SelectedIndexChanged event does not get fired on Index change

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cascadingdropdown, selectedindexchanged

I have the following `dropdownList` control in asp.net

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlMerchantCity" runat="server"></asp:dropdownlist>
```

And I want to call a method on its `SelectedIndexChanged` event but it doesn't get into the SelectedIndexChanged event's body. What is the problem with my code?

```
Protected Sub ddlMerchantCity_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlMerchantCity.SelectedIndexChanged
            Response.Write("<script>alert('from selectindex')</script>")
            LoadMerchant()
        End Sub
```

EDIT:
Even adding the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` in the asp.net dropdownlist doesn't work

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlMerchantCity" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMerchantCity_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:dropdownlist>
```

Comment: Add `onselectedindexchanged="ddlMerchantCity_SelectedIndexChanged"` and `AutoPostBack="true"`  to the dropdownlist

Comment: Add `AutoPostBack="true"` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that you have a method to do something when this event occurs. You can invoke this method by either defining it in the aspx markup:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlMerchantCity" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMerchantCity_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:dropdownlist>
```

Or you can set in your code behind:

```
AddHandler ddlMerchantCity.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Me.ddlMerchantcity_SelectedIndexChanged
```

I'd rather do it via markup though. A lot quicker and easier.

/Edit:
If adding `OnSelectedIndexChanged` does not help, you might have to set [`AutoPostback="true"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback(v=vs.100).aspx)

To cite MSDN on the AutoPostBack description:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether a postback to the server automatically occurs when the user changes the list selection.

Comment: Resolved after adding `AutoPostBack="true"` property of the `dropdownlist `control